# Get all results before paginate() i Laravel 5.1

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.1

Is it possible to get all query results before paginate it.

```
$results = Cars::select('cars.*', 'car_images.*') ... ->paginate(10);
```

This query return 1000+ results but pagination show only 10. I want to get all cars.id's which I can use in other query to show all possible parameters for 1000+ cars from result.

Cars

```
id  |  brand | model | year |
```

Parameters

```
id  |  param_name 
---------------------
1   |  color
2   |  fuel
```

Car_parameters

```
car_id  | param_id | param_value 
---------------------------------
1       |  1       | red
1       |  2       | diesel
```

If there is a better solution I would love to hear

Comment: I have more than 30K cars in table 'cars'. When I do search query which results 500 cars but pagination show only 30 per page. On side filters i need to show all possible parameters for complete results ( all different parameters for 500 cars )

Comment: Can you post your models also? From your tables structure I understand that you have many to many relatioship between Cars and Parameters with pivot table named Car_parameters with extra field "param_value". Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the values of all parameters using the following query.

```
 $parameters = DB::table('Car_parameters')->select('param_value')->distinct()->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want all the results, just get them with `all()`

```
Cars::select('cars.*', 'car_images.*') ... ->all();
```

But if you need only the Car ids for another query I suggest do this:

```
 $carIds= (array) DB::table('cars')
        ->selectRaw('GROUP_CONCAT(id) as ids')
        ->where(...)
        ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can get All car id's by

```
Cars::with('car_images')->lists('id')->array();
```